# Android Studio cant resolve a jar within another jar

Tags: android, android-studio

This a android project, it works well int eclipse(ADT); when I import it in Android Studio, the app can run too, but the app can't load the inner jar,
what should I do?

The demo address: http://images2016-10035298.cos.myqcloud.com/BaiduSDKDemo.zip

[image: Android Studio error]

Comment: You should show the entirety of that build.gradle file, particularly the bottom part where the dependencies are listed.